# Do solutions to a polynomial in $m$ variables always either span $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ or have a zero measure in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial $F(x_{1},\dots,x_{m})$ with real coefficients in $m$ variables $\vec{x}$=$(x_{1},\dots, x_{m})$

Let $P$ denote the set defined by $P=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}: F(\vec{x})=0\}$.

In addition, assume that $F(\vec{x}_{0})\neq 0$ for some $\vec{x}_{0}$.

Does it immediately follow that $P$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$? I tried to find relevant literature from the algebraic geometry, but could not find an answer for my question. Thanks.

Comment: I will not show this here. Just two comments: (1) $P$ does not have interior points since $F$ is analytic. (2) Let $x\in P$ be a regular point, i.e., $\nabla F(x)\neq 0$. Then $P$, in a neighborhoood $U$ of $x$, is a differentiable manifold of some dimension. By (1), the dimension is less than $m$. So, $P\cap U$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any vector $\vec{u}$, $\{t: F(\vec{x_0} + t \vec{u}) = 0\}$ is finite.  Integrate in spherical coordinates.

Comment: It's a polynomial in one variable.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this answer?  I agree that the set you define is finite.  I assume you mean to integrate in spherical coordinates centered at the point $\vec{x_0}$, but, then what?

Comment: Let $S$ be the unit sphere.  For any Lebesgue measurable set $A \subset R^m$, with $I_A$ its indicator function, by Fubini's theorem the measure of $A$ is $ \int_S d\vec{s}\; \int_0^\infty dr\;  r^{m-1} I_A(\vec{x_0} + r\vec{s})$ where $d\vec{s}$ is Lebesgue measure on $S$ with the proper normalization.  But if $A \cap \{\vec{x_0} + r\vec{s}:\; 0 < r < \infty\}$ is finite, the inner integral is $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: To apply Fubini's, we need to require that the integral is less than infinity. How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Actually, Tonelli's theorem is the version where the integrand is nonnegative and not necessarily integrable.  But even without that, you could integrate from $0$ to finite $R$ and then take $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks!